# sweetalert does'nt work when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, css, sweetalert

Good day, I am trying to use sweetalert onclick but when I click on the button nothing happens, only the alert is displayed when refreshing the page, what I want to achieve is that when clicking on the button the alert appears, not when refreshing the page.

I am trying to use sweetalert, it is supposed that when I click on a button should appear the alert but this does not happen in fact, at startup it appears automatically every time I load the page, what I want to achieve is that only when I click on the button the alert appears, not every time the page is refreshed.

```
function successAlert()
Swal.fire(
   'saved!',   
   'success'
 )
```

```
 .show-example-btn {
  font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
```

```
<script src="sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert2.min.css">
<div class="showcase sweet">
      <button
        class="show-example-btn"
        aria-label="Show SweetAlert2 success message"
        onclick="successAlert()">
        save
      </button>
      <pre data-example-id="sweetAlert"></pre>
    </div>
```

Comment: and where do you call the function `executeExample()` inside your onclick?

Comment: sorry, I copied the code wrong, an apology, I'll edit it right away, thank you very much.

Comment: Typo. The function definition is missing `{` and `}`

Comment: That and also you `success` string is in the place of the `text`, which means your `success` icon won't show

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't notice that mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad function definition, missing `{` and `}` like Quentin mentioned in the comments and also the structure of a basic swal alert goes like this

```
Swal.fire(
   title,
   text,
   icon
)
```

You were adding `success` message where the text should go and your icon would never show on your alert. You should change it to something like this:

```js
function successAlert() {
  Swal.fire(
    'saved!',
    'You successfully pressed the button',
    'success'
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<div class="showcase sweet">
  <button class="show-example-btn" aria-label="Show SweetAlert2 success message" onclick="successAlert()">
        save
      </button>
  <pre data-example-id="sweetAlert"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried everything, your answer worked for me!